# jQuery Cycle Plugin, add class to current slide thumbnail/link

Tags: jquery, css, class, hyperlink, jquery-cycle

I'm currently using this jQuery Cycle Plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

And I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Slideshow cycle init
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      speed: 500
    });
});
function setSlide(index) {
     $('#slideshow').cycle(index);
}

// current link
 $(document).ready(function(){   
   $('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("current").removeClass("current"); // this is what I'm trying to work on..
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="slideshow" class="products-slideshow">
  <img src="product-slides/1.jpg" />
  <img src="product-slides/2.jpg" />
  <img src="product-slides/3.jpg" />
  <img src="product-slides/4.jpg" />
  <img src="product-slides/5.jpg" />
</div>

<ul class="products-slideshow-thumbs">
  <li><a onclick="setSlide(0);"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a onclick="setSlide(1);"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a onclick="setSlide(2);"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a onclick="setSlide(3);"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/4.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a onclick="setSlide(4);"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/5.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Right now, it works as it should slideshow-wise and style-wise.  However, I'm trying to add a class to the currently-shown thumbnail link (wrapped in the 'products-slideshow-thumbs' class) using jQuery.
The jQuery I have in the code above adds the class when I click on the thumbnail link, but when I click on another thumbnail link, BOTH thumbnail links retain the "current" class.  Is there a way to make sure only ONE link (the current link) keeps the "current" class?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!  Thank you for reading.

Comment: could you possibly show a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("current").removeClass("current"); // this is what I'm trying to work on..
    });
  });
```

into this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').click(function(){
      $('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').removeClass("current");
      $(this).addClass("current");
    });
  });
```

See what I did there? Before adding the current-class to `$(this)`, i removed it from all the other `products-slideshow-thumbs li a`'s

Comment: Anytime mate, I'm glad I could be of help